# How to create a co-occurrence Matrix using R

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying build a co-occurance matrix in my data. I have dataframe with 141 rows and 544 columns. Each column contains either 0 and 1. Sample of dataset:

```
    OTU_1 OTU_10 OTU_100 OTU_101 OTU_109
    1      1       1       0        0
    1      1       0       0        1
    1      1       0       0        0
    1      1       1       1        1
    1      1       1       1        1
```

Original structure of my data:

```
data.frame':    141 obs. of  544 variables:
$ OTU_1    : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ OTU_10   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ OTU_100  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
```

Now I want to compare one column against other other columns and one row at a time. Hence I tried the following code:

```
gen.cyscd_df <- function(x){
help.df <- data.frame(otu1 = row.names(x)[1] , otu2 = rownames(x), counts= 0)
for (i in 1:ncol(x)){
help.df <- rbind.data.frame(help.df, data.frame(otu1 = col.names(x)[i] , 
                                                otu2 = col.names(x)[i:length(colnames(x))], 
                                                counts= 0))
}
row.names(help.df) <- NULL 
return(help.df) 
}
single.otu.df <- gen.cyscd_df(bin_OTU_tab)
```

The str of the above code is:

```
data.frame':    91961 obs. of  3 variables:
$ otu1  : Factor w/ 141 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ otu2  : Factor w/ 141 levels "1","10","100",..: 1 54 65 76 87 98 109 120 131 2 ...
$ counts: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

The next step is to replace the column counts based on the co-occurance of 1 OTU to other OTU

```
single.otu.matrix_row <- function(x){
single.otu.df2 <- single.otu.df
for (otu1 in 1:nrow(x)){
for(otu2 in 1:nrow(x)){
  if(x[otu1,1] ==1 && x[otu2,1] ==1) {
    single.otu.df[otu1+otu2] <- 1}
}
}
return(single.otu.df2)
}
x<-single.otu.matrix_row(as.matrix(bin_OTU_tab[1:nrow(bin_OTU_tab),1]))
```

But in the counts columns, I could not replace the 0 values.

```
data.frame':    91961 obs. of  3 variables:
     $ otu1  : Factor w/ 141 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ otu2  : Factor w/ 141 levels "1","10","100",..: 1 54 65 76 87 98 109 120 131 2 ...
     $ counts: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

But the expected output is (for the first row)

```
OTU1 OTU2 Counts
1     10    1
1     100   1
1     101   0
1     109   0
```

Where I have gone wrong. Kindly guide me

Comment: It is really difficult to answer questions without data. Can you share a small sample of your data or create a fake dataset with say 5 rows and 8 columns and show expected based on that?

Comment: @RonakShah, I have edited my query with sample dataset

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the data that you have shared ?

Comment: @RonakShah, I have shared my expected output

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but thought this might be helpful. You can use `apply` and go through each row individually. The first two columns with be pairwise combinations of the column names. Using `outer` you build a matrix multiplying each element of a given row (default is `*`). Using `lower.tri` of the matrix will match the result (e.g., two 1's to give a 1 in the matrix) with the column names. Perhaps this may be helpful for others in the future.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  setNames(data.frame(
    cbind(
      t(combn(names(df), 2)),
      (mat <- outer(x, x))[lower.tri(mat)]
      )
    ), 
    c("OTU1","OTU2","Counts"))
})
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
      OTU1    OTU2 Counts
1    OTU_1  OTU_10      1
2    OTU_1 OTU_100      1
3    OTU_1 OTU_101      0
4    OTU_1 OTU_109      0
5   OTU_10 OTU_100      1
6   OTU_10 OTU_101      0
7   OTU_10 OTU_109      0
8  OTU_100 OTU_101      0
9  OTU_100 OTU_109      0
10 OTU_101 OTU_109      0

[[2]]
      OTU1    OTU2 Counts
1    OTU_1  OTU_10      1
2    OTU_1 OTU_100      0
3    OTU_1 OTU_101      0
4    OTU_1 OTU_109      1
5   OTU_10 OTU_100      0
6   OTU_10 OTU_101      0
7   OTU_10 OTU_109      1
8  OTU_100 OTU_101      0
9  OTU_100 OTU_109      0
10 OTU_101 OTU_109      0

[[3]]
      OTU1    OTU2 Counts
1    OTU_1  OTU_10      1
2    OTU_1 OTU_100      0
3    OTU_1 OTU_101      0
4    OTU_1 OTU_109      0
5   OTU_10 OTU_100      0
6   OTU_10 OTU_101      0
7   OTU_10 OTU_109      0
8  OTU_100 OTU_101      0
9  OTU_100 OTU_109      0
10 OTU_101 OTU_109      0

[[4]]
      OTU1    OTU2 Counts
1    OTU_1  OTU_10      1
2    OTU_1 OTU_100      1
3    OTU_1 OTU_101      1
4    OTU_1 OTU_109      1
5   OTU_10 OTU_100      1
6   OTU_10 OTU_101      1
7   OTU_10 OTU_109      1
8  OTU_100 OTU_101      1
9  OTU_100 OTU_109      1
10 OTU_101 OTU_109      1

[[5]]
      OTU1    OTU2 Counts
1    OTU_1  OTU_10      1
2    OTU_1 OTU_100      1
3    OTU_1 OTU_101      1
4    OTU_1 OTU_109      1
5   OTU_10 OTU_100      1
6   OTU_10 OTU_101      1
7   OTU_10 OTU_109      1
8  OTU_100 OTU_101      1
9  OTU_100 OTU_109      1
10 OTU_101 OTU_109      1
```